# I live in the UK and want to buy some shares on the unlisted New Zealand Stock Exchange

Tags: stocks, united-kingdom, purchase

I live in the UK and want to buy some shares that are Unlisted within the New Zealand stock exchange and I should also like to buy shares on the NZX. which is the best way to do this from the UK?

Jonathan Simon

Comment: Note that in NZ the term "Unlisted" may mean something somewhat different to what it does in the rest of the world, due to the creation of an exchange where unlisted shares can be, er, listed.  See https://www.nzherald.co.nz/business/it-was-a-quiet-day-too-quiet-at-unlisted/3VU3XEAODDF77IN5HW3N5LUPTI/ and the Unlisted exchange itself at https://www.usx.co.nz/ (much clicking of disclaimers and captchas needed to access the latter link).

Comment: There are some UK brokers who claim to provide access to the NZ market.  This might be a useful starting point (but possibly a bit out of date): https://the-international-investor.com/brokers/charles-stanley .  It won't be cheap: telephone dealing charges (online not an option), commissions, FX costs...

Comment: @timday That sounds similar to the US OTC stock market.